# Formula for analytic function using Schwartz's Lemma

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

I've been working on the following problem from Conway's complex variables book:

> Suppose $f$ is analytic in some region containing $\overline{B(0,1)}$ and $|f(z)|=1$ where $|z|=1$. Find a formula for $f$. (Hint: First consider the case where $f$ has no zeros in $B(0,1$).

First, we know that if $f$ has no zeros in $B(0,1)$, it is a constant (this was an earlier problem in the book).

In general, I believe $f$ has the form
$$f=c\prod_{i=1}^m\phi_{a_i}(z)^{m_i}$$
where $\phi_a(z)=\frac{z-a}{1-\overline{a}z}$ and $|c|=1$. Here's an incomplete justification as to why:

First, if $f$ has one zero of order $1$ at, say $a$, it is one-to-one in a neighborhood of $a$ so $f$ has the form $f=c\phi_a$ where $|c|=1$ (I realized there's a problem here, because to apply the theorem which tells us that, we need $f$ to be one-to-one on all of $B(0,1)$, not just a neighborhood of $a$.

Second, if $f$ has a zero of order $m$ at $a$, then write $f(z)=(z-a)^{m-1}h(z)$ where $h$ has a root of order $1$ at $a$. Define $g(z)=(1-\overline{a}z)^{m-1}$, which has a root of order $1$ at $a$, to write
$$f(z)=\frac{(z-a)^{m-1}}{(1-\overline{a}z)^{m-1}}g(z)$$
and apply the above to obtain $f(z)=c\phi_a(z)^m$.

Now for any $f$, it has finitely many zeros in $B(0,1)$ and so I want to just take the product of the above, but I'm not sure how to justify that, either.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're very close. If the zeroes of $f$ in the disk are labelled $a_i$, how many zeroes does $f/\prod_i \phi_{a_i}$ have in the disk?

Comment: Hi Unit, I understood how your solution solves the problem, but do you know an intuitive way to see that we must expect that $f(z) = c \prod_i \phi_{a_i}$ with $|c| = 1$ without know previously that $f$ is a finite Blaschke product? I thought use the theorem $2.5$ on chapter $6$ of the Conway's book, which is the same theorem commented by the author of this OP, and consider the case when $f$ has only one root and do an induction on order of this zero, but I don't know if $f$ is injective. I wrote $f$ in his power series around of the zero, but I couldn't conclude the injectiveness of $f$.